# Unknown class <class name> in Interface Builder file, but only iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting an error which says "Unknown class  in Interface Builder file". I have found lots of answers for this question but in mine it only happens on iOS 5. If I use iOS 6 it works fine. Why would it only fail on iOS 5?

Comment: What is the unknown class? NSLayoutConstraint?

Comment: It is a custom subclass of UICollectionViewController.

Comment: UICollectionViewController is not available in iOS 5 (was introduced with iOS 6).